# get_the_date(); displays the date of wordpress installation, not post

Tags: php, html, wordpress, date, timestamp

I'm having trouble displaying the date for each post in wordpress. For each post it displays the installation date it seems, and not the post date (each post was published on different days, but all now display the same date which seems random). Tried putting the get_the_date(); in the for each lopp without luck. Does anyone know why?

```
$postsnumber = $nm_theme_options['numberposts']; 
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => "$postsnumber" );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        $date = get_the_date(); 
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){                 
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .  $date .' '. $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to fetch the date for each post, which means you'd need to call it *in the loop*?

Comment: As mentioined putting it in the loop did not make a difference, but yeah, I'll keep it there.

Comment: Well please show *how* you put it in there - in particular, did you use the post ID as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem!

```
<?php
        $postsnumber = $nm_theme_options['numberposts']; 
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => "$postsnumber" );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){    
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .  date('d.m.y', strtotime($recent['post_date'])) .' '. $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
    ?>
```

Sorry for beeing new at this, but thanks for your help!